# How to implent facebook event tracking pixel code in open cart 1.5

Tags: php, opencart

As per the **Facebook** instruction i am placing `Facebook pixel code` in the header section of `index.php` file, but after this my google sitemap is giving an **HTTP** header error.
Now please help me to figure out where to place my **facebook** pixel code, my website is built on open cart 1.5

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
 <script>
 !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
 {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
 n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
 if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';  
 n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
 t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
 s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,document,'script',
 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
 fbq('init', '1**********7'); 
 fbq('track', 'PageView');
 fbq('track', 'InitiateCheckout');
 </script>
 <noscript>
 <img height="1" width="1" 
 src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=177561923016647&ev=PageView
 &noscript=1"/>
 </noscript>
 <!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Comment: can please show your code.

Comment: add this code in you question .

Comment: Put this code with the question

Answer (score 0):

Facebook tracking codes or any other codes which requires a user to add it to the header needs to be added in the following file

```
catalog > view > theme > {theme_name} > template > common > header.tpl
```

You will have to look for the section to add it in as per instructions from the vendor (in this case facebook)

**NOTE: You are not encouraged to change core files or in this case template files. As such have a look at [vqmod](https://www.google.co.za/search?q=vqmod%20opencart%201.5&oq=vqmod%20opencart%201.5) and how to use it to avoid such changes in the core files**